# How to get current mouse cursor position on QWidget?

Tags: c++, qt, position, cursor

I have to receive the current mouse cursor coordinates in mm/inch, while the cursor hovers over a QWidget.
Already tried: mouseMoveEvent

```
void darstellung::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event){

qDebug() << event->pos();
}
```

I activated the MouseTracking in the MainWindow constructor as well.

```
setMouseTracking(true);
```

It seems that the mouseMoveEvent will only return the cursor position, if the left mouse button is pressed.

Comment: Are you trying to catch these events in a mainwindow or a completely unrelated widget?

Comment: I am catching the Events in a seperate class called darstellung, related to QWidget. "class darstellung : public QWidget" @thuga

Comment: `setMouseTracking(true)` should give you move events even when no button is pressed. Without it the widget will indeed only receive move events when a button is pressed

Comment: I cant find the right Event in the Qt documentation for QMouseEvent, smb. knows how to handle this?

Comment: @Jonas As Kevin said `setMouseTracking(true)` should allow you to get mouse position with `mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)` regardless if a button is pressed or not. You can then use QScreen to get the screen dpi and convert pixels to inches

Comment: You say you set mouse tracking to `true` on the mainwindow. But did you enable it for your widget?

Comment: @thuga thank you, i just forgot to relate the method to the widget:     "ui->widget->setMouseTracking(true);" Now i just need to convert the output in mm/inch

Comment: Try diving by [`QScreen::physicalDotsPerInchX`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscreen.html#physicalDotsPerInchX-prop). It will depend on each system to provide accurate information about your display.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, hasMouseTracking() returns false on widget

my Workaround:

```
//position relative to window|       |you might add some ->parentWidget()
QPoint relPos = QCursor::pos() - this->window()->pos();
```

the positions are relative to virtual screen-coordinates on windows. eg: my widget is displayed at the 2nd monitor, which is left to the 1st -> that gives x=-1000 y=200 (in pixel)

check capability:

```
if(this->hasMouseTracking() ){
            this->setMouseTracking(true);
            qDebug("mousetracking on");
}else qDebug("\nmousetracking not available\n");
```

some useless hints:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html#grabMouse (this one is no good practice)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30960032

> So in your constructor you can add a line
> this->viewport()->setMouseTracking(true) and then override
> mouseMoveEvent