# "mouseMoveEvent" only triggers by clicking and dragging but I need to detect it hovering over

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm trying to color a label whenever the mouse passes over the program or **"MainWindow"** and the program only changes the color if I click and drag, any other operation like just clicking or just dragging does not trigger the **"mouseMoveEvent"** function

```
import utils
from utils.INTERFACE_FUNCIONALITIES.FOOD_DEV import Ui_MainWindow
from utils import interface_func as i_fun
from utils import template

p = template.Product()
c = template.Client()

i_fun = i_fun.Interface()

    
class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.show()
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event): 
        self.rmm_lb_logo.setStyleSheet("background-color: red;") <-- TRY COLOR 
        #self.rmm_lb_logo.setText('Mouse coords: ( %d : %d )' % (event.x(), event.y()))


import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    p.view()
    c.view()
    i_fun.functionalties(w)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mouse tracking won't be very useful for this specific situation, because the objective is to get mouse events within the boundaries of the window, not that of the widget. Also, the move event is only received when actively moving the mouse, but this will fail the result if the window *becomes* under the mouse for any reason (for instance, another window that was above it becomes hidden or closed). Finally, the mouse tracking doesn't allow to know when the mouse actually leaves the widget.

The simplest solution is to override the [`enterEvent()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#enterEvent) and [`leaveEvent()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#leaveEvent):

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        
    def enterEvent(self, event):
        super().enterEvent(event)
        self.rmm_lb_logo.setStyleSheet("background-color: red;")

    def leaveEvent(self, event):
        super().leaveEvent(event)
        self.rmm_lb_logo.setStyleSheet("")
```

Comment: You're welcome. Please don't change the title of the question with "solved", this is not a forum. Instead, if an answer solves your problem, you can mark it as accepted by clicking the gray check on its left (when you'll have at least 50 points, you'll also be able to *vote* questions and answers). Please take your time to review the [tour] to better understand how StackOverflow works.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'm new here, so I'll see if I look at the tour myself.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you should post a minimal working example. I don't have your `utils` module.

You already found the first possible problem which is `setMouseTracking`. Only when that is set to true, will the `mouseMoveEvent` be called.

If you still don't get a `mouseMoveEvent`, then this means some other widget accepts the `mouseMoveEvent`.

E.g. try this minimal *working* example:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent=parent)

        self.setMouseTracking(True)

        self.label = QLabel("Mouse coordinates", parent)
        # Without this mouseMoveEvent of QLabel will be called
        # instead of mouseMoveEvent of MainWindow!
        self.label.setMouseTracking(True)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.label)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: red;")
        self.label.setText('Mouse coordinates: ( %d : %d )' % (event.x(), event.y()))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

As annotated in the code, the QLabel will accept the mouseMoveEvent meaning it will not get propagated to MainWindow. The MainWindow's mouseMoveEvent is called, when removing the QLabel and only changing the color or when turning mouse tracking off on the QLabel.

Turning off mouse tracking, however, is only a hack. Instead, you should define the `mouseMoveEvent` in the widget into which it belongs. If that isn't possible because you want to react to **all** mouse moves, then try [installing an event filter on the application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1935021/getting-mousemoveevents-in-qt).

See also the detailed description of [QMouseEvent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmouseevent.html#details):

> Mouse move events will occur only when a mouse button is pressed down,
> unless mouse tracking has been enabled with
> QWidget::setMouseTracking().
>
> Qt automatically grabs the mouse when a mouse button is pressed inside
> a widget; the widget will continue to receive mouse events until the
> last mouse button is released.
>
> A mouse event contains a special accept flag that indicates whether
> the receiver wants the event. You should call ignore() if the mouse
> event is not handled by your widget. A mouse event is propagated up
> the parent widget chain until a widget accepts it with accept(), or an
> event filter consumes it.

Comment: The OP is asking to change the label stylesheet when the mouse moves on *the window*, not just on the label. In your case it works because the label occupies almost all the window and is set as a central widget, but if there are other objects (and this is the case since they're using a designer file which sets a generic QWidget as central widget), it wouldn't work. Besides, the color is not reset when the mouse leaves the window.

Comment: Thank you, I understood. In this case I thought there would be the possibility of capturing just setting the "mouse tracking" to the "main window" or "centralWidget", but apparently it is not working, the only way I found is to apply the mouse tracking to the desired frame, which in my case solves what I was looking for. If you want to see the project files here is the link to the repository on github: https://github.com/UPraggy/FOOD_DEV @mxmlnkn